# Create ArFragment object inside another Fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on a project with ArCore.

I'm trying to create an instance of the ArFragment object inside another Fragment. It keeps returning null.

I have one Activity, MainActivity, and I have a total of 3 fragments that are used within a ViewPager.

**ArFragment returns null - Image**

[image]

When i'm trying to create an ArFragment object from a 2nd activity, it works. But passing the Arfragment from a second activity to the Fragment results in a poor user-experience, so i'd rather avoid that.

Is there any way to create an ArFragment within another Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should invoke `getChildFragmentManager` in `onActivityCreated`.

This is my code, it ran correctly. (Sorry this is Kotlin)

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var arFragment: ARFragment

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, @Nullable container: ViewGroup?, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // fragment_sample contains ARFragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        arFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ar_fragment) as MyARFragment
        ...
     }
     ...
```

[completely code](https://tech.mizuki.io/post/14/)

Answer (score 0):

I remember vaguely that you need to use a different function to find fragments inside fragments. This is what works for me without problems:

arFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ar_fragment);

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In Android an `Activity` can contain several `Fragments` inside itself. When `Activity` is running, you can manipulate each `Fragment` independently, such as add or remove them.

Each *Fragment* can be considered a *View Controller*. Android allows you put a ***Child Fragment*** inside ***Parent Fragment***.

Here's how you can create one ArFragment inside another one:

In Kotlin:

```
val arcoreFragment = MyARFragment()

childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
    add(R.id.ar_fragment, arcoreFragment)
    commit()
}
```

In Java:

```
ArFragment arcoreFragment = new MyARFragment();

FragmentTransaction ta = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ta.add(R.id.ar_fragment, arcoreFragment).commit();
```

[image]